# Area of Mandelbrot set: Uniform convergence in Laurent series method

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-dynamics

I am reading Ewing and Schober's paper on analytically computing the area of the Mandelbrot set and I hope, in a shred of such, that someone might have an idea why swapping an integral and sum is justified. The paper can be foud on https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01385497, p.69.

A diffeomorphism $$\phi(z)=\sum_{m=-1}^{\infty} b_mz^{-m}$$ maps the exterior of the unit disk to the exterior of the Mandelbrot set.  The image $\phi(C_r)$ of a circle of radius $r>1$ forms a region $M( R)$ and we wish to find the area of $M(1)$.

Using Green's Theorem, they give the following expression for the area
$$ -\frac12 \int \sum_{n,m\geq -1} m\overline{b_n}b_m(1/r)^{n+m}e^{(m-n)i\theta} d\theta. $$
I am trying to understand:

**Why does the sum** 
$$\sum_{n,m\geq -1} m\overline{b_n}b_m(1/r)^{n+m}e^{(m-n)i\theta}$$
**converges uniformly so that swapping the integral and the sum is justified?**

I tried to bound it by a geometric series but the trouble is that the coefficients are not constant and also $r>1$. The first coeffients are $b_0=-1/2,b_2=-1/4,b_3=15/128,b4=0,b_5=-47/1024$ but computing these coefficients seems to be a delicate matter. Does the sum converge because these coefficients converge very quickly to zero?

Comment: https://www.mrob.com/pub/muency/laurentseries.html discusses convergence rate and coefficient calculations, but doesn't answer your main question

Comment: https://mathr.co.uk/mandelbrot/log_abs_b_n.png plots $\log|b_n|$

Comment: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Jung50e.png illustrates the conformal mapping from complement of disc to complement of Mandelbrot set

Answer (score 1):

Idea: the (three) terms with $m = -1$ or $n = -1$ are irrelevant, ignore it. Now, group the terms with $m + n = k$: 
$$
\sum_{k\ge 0}\left(\sum_{n+m = k}
m\overline{b_n}b_m e^{(m-n)i\theta}\right)r^{-k}
$$
If $|b_n|\le 1$, we have
$$\left|\sum_{n+m = k}
m\overline{b_n}b_m e^{(m-n)i\theta}\right|\le\sum_{m=0}^k m = k(k+1)/2.$$
Finally, take a fixed $ R > 1$ and apply the M-test in the interval $r\ge R$.

Comment: @Claude, I missed the $r>1$.Then, $(b_n)$ must be $\to 0$ faster.

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2} k (k+1) r^{-k} = \frac{r^2}{(r - 1)^3}$ according to Wolfram Alpha (for $r > 1$)